# MySQL Select with MAX() and GROUP BY return correct max result but not correct id

Tags: mysql

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `capacity_log` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_occurred` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`ip_address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`order_product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`serial` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`used_capacity` BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`aux2` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`request` BLOB NULL,
`retry_count` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fetch_time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`response` BLOB NULL,
`custom_fetch_time` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

By executing a query I want to take the row id and the maximum used capacity for each order_product_id for each week. The request returns the correct maximum capacity, but does not return the correct id.

```
SELECT c.id, MAX(c.used_capacity) AS `max_capacity`
FROM capacity_log c
WHERE c.date_occurred < '2020-10-1' AND c.aux2 IS NULL 
GROUP BY
    YEAR(c.date_occurred), WEEK(c.date_occurred),
    c.order_product_id
```

Comment: Every record which appears in your current result set is actually an aggregate of _many_ records corresponding to each year and week.  The question here is, _which_ `id` value do you want to display, and what is the logic behind it.

Comment: You probably don't need the grouping at all - simply get the id and capacity, sort by capacity in descending order and take only the top row.

Comment: You should select `c.order_product_id` instead of `c.id`...

Comment: I want the row id that matches the max result

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
SELECT c.id, c.used_capacity
FROM capacity_log c
WHERE  max_capacity = (
  SELECT  MAX(c.used_capacity) AS `max_capacity`
    FROM capacity_log c
   WHERE c.date_occurred < '2020-10-1' 
     AND c.aux2 IS NULL 
   GROUP 
      BY YEAR(c.date_occurred)
       , WEEK(c.date_occurred)
       , c.order_product_id)
```

Comment: I think you mean `WHERE used_capacity = ..`